# Will educated Tropicans take jobs requiring  lower or no educational qualifications?

Tags: tropico-3

In Tropico 1, I remember that educated Tropicans will occasionally take jobs requiring lower qualifications if they either can't find a job that needs their educational qualifications, or if the job satisfaction for those jobs are low. For example, a college-educated Tropican being a farmer. I haven't noticed this yet in my multiple playthroughs of Tropico 3.

Does the same thing happen with Tropico 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the posts in this thread: yes, the same thing can happen.

[Some exceprts](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/strategy/tropico3/show_msgs.php?pid=955046&topic_id=m-1-52818097):

> Strange, every single one of my citizens had a HS education, most even college, and they still worked the farms, albeit for a higher wage, but it's not like I couldn't afford that or anything
>
> I had a game where very early on when educated Tropicans are in short
> supply, a college educated female named 'Ana' refused to take a $10
> teaching job over her $5 farm job.
>
> The chance of a tropican getting into a job depends on the job
> statisfaction and prior experience. They won't leave a 9$ farm for a
> 12$ sweat shop factory. Basically it means that you're not paying HS
> educated enough.

I'm looking around for a more reliable source, which will give a more detailed explanation on why this happens but have not yet found one yet. Either way though, four people in that thread reported this happening so obviously it does happen.

Comment: Thanks. I think you might have forgotten to link to the thread you are quoting, though.

Comment: @galacticninja Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.